# join quoted strings with variable in powershell

Tags: powershell, string-concatenation, single-quotes

I'm coming from a *nix scripting background and I'm a total newbie to powershell and Windows admin in general. I'm trying to write a script that will check the SmartHost value on a collection of exchange/IIS smtp virtual hosts. I'm trying to figure out how to insert the looped variable into the ADSI query string but the + operator doesn't do the trick:

```
$hosts = @("host1","host2")

foreach ($hostname in $hosts) {
$SMTPSvc = [ADSI]'IIS://' + $hostname + '/smtpsvc/1'
echo $SMTPSvc.SmartHost
}
```

Using the + with single or double quotes gives me this error:

`Method invocation failed because [System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'.
At line:3 char:1
+ $SMTPSvc = [ADSI]'IIS://' + $hostname + '/smtpsvc/1'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound`

What would be the proper or preferred way to insert the looped host value into the ADSI query string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like an order of operations issue. The first part of the query:

```
[ADSI]'IIS://'
```

is being converted to the query string and then you try to add a string to the resulting [System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry] object. Since that class does not provide an addition operator, it fails. Instead, generate the entire string first before constructing the query by enclosing it in brackets:

```
$SMTPSvc = [ADSI]('IIS://' + $hostname + '/smtpsvc/1')
```

Comment: `$SMTPSvc = [ADSI]"IIS://$hostname/smtpsvc/1"` would also work in this case.